# Wordpress - estimate used product

Tags: plugins, e-commerce, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I'd need to add to wordpress the "evaluate your used product" automated function. I thought about something with multistep forms but I don't know if it is the definitive choice.

Comment: What do you mean estimate their used product - provide a calculator for them to enter some information and tell them how much to buy? That's going to be specific to the domain you're working in and whatever business rules you have. I expect you'd have to build that yourself if you can't find a plugin that already does this (and I don't think we can recommend one)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I wasn't able to explain it well but I mean something like the following website swappie.com/de-en/sell/iphone

Comment: Sorry, yes I understand - I thought you meant "quantity of product used" but you meant "estimate value of a product customer is trading in". I'd guess there are forms & wizards plugins you can use for that, but I've never done that myself to recommend one.

Comment: Yes, I was just updating the post because I realized I wrote it very bad. Actually I was just exploring multistep form but I didn't find something good.